# where does default value show up in swagger node request?

Tags: node.js, swagger

I have the below route:

```
/myroute:
    x-swagger-router-controller: myroute
    post:
        operationId: createSomething
        parameters:
            - name: payload
              in: body
              required: true
              schema:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                      somedefault:
                          type: string
                          default: teststring
```

and in my `createSomething` function I try to console log the values:

`console.log(req.swagger.params.payload.value)` and I expect to see

`{somedefault: 'teststring'}`

But I see nothing for `somedefault`. Am I misunderstanding where the default parameters should show up in swagger-node?

Comment: I think this is related to a bug not implemented yet in sway https://github.com/apigee-127/sway/issues/102

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://swagger.io/specification/#parameterDefault), `default` is ignored if `required` is true.

Comment: This is true only for parameter-level defaults, e.g. if a query or header parameter is `required` and has a `default` value. OP's example is different - the request body is what is `required`, and it can be both `{}` and `{"somedefault": "abcde"}`, and `default` applies to a specific property (`somedefault`), not the whole object.